# How to produce summary statistics in Stata

Tags: stata, summary

I'm trying to create summary statistics on certain variables for people who work in one job, work in another job, and then compare that to those who work in neither of those jobs. I was able to get the code for a summary for those who worked in either job, but I am not sure how to create a summary excluding those jobs. Here is what I have so far:

```
tabstat lwage educ hours exper, by(construc) stat(mean sd min max) nototal

tabstat lwage educ hours exper, by(agric) stat(mean sd min max) nototal
```

I thought there could be a way of simply summarizing the variables by both construc and agric, but that didn't work. Any help would be great!

Comment: You can use a *if-statement* like `tabstat lwage educ hours exper if construc == 0 & agric == 0, stat(mean sd min max) nototal`

Answer (score 0):

As Harre said in the comments, the solution is:

```
tabstat lwage educ hours exper if construc == 0 & agric == 0, stat(mean sd min max) nototal
```

Had the syntax wrong when I initially tried the if statement

Comment: Alternatively you can construct a 3-category-variable using `gen` and `replace if` and use `by()`.